# UPDATE stored procedure from Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm writing an application that on page load pulls information from SQL based on an ID from the url and then I convert it to a Int.

```
request_id = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
RequestID = Convert.ToInt32(request_id);
```

I am then trying to submit changes on the page back to the database in an SQL update stored procedure.

If I print to the page the values of the above `RequestID` and `request_id`... I get the same number.. which is fine.

However I have two submit buttons on my page.. when I click the first one it pops up the following.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server"
ConfirmText="Want to Save?" 
TargetControlID="submit_btn" 
DisplayModalPopupID="btnSave_ModalPopupExtender"        
ConfirmOnFormSubmit="true">
</ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnSave_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
TargetControlID="submit_btn" 
PopupControlID="Panel1" 
DropShadow="true" 
CancelControlID="btnCancel"
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="Panel_css"  >
<asp:Label ID="sqlErrorLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<p style="margin-left:40px; margin-right:40px; text-align:center">Are you sure you wish to     commit this to the database?</p>
<div style="position:relative; left:23%">
<asp:Button id="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnOK_Click" CssClass="submit" />
<asp:Button id="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="submit"  />
</div>
```

And its between clicking the second button and running the stored procedure that the RequestID gets lost as when I print it out on the page it equals 0 when before it was 255 (for this example)

I know my code works because if I replace my parameter in the stored procedure with a fixed value it works fine.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: I'm writing code to update a MS SQL database if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store the request Id in hidden field. it should work fine